# Data Access in a Multi-Tenant App structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate

Several Accounts are going to use this application. Each account will have its own set of users. We want to implement Access Control in such a manner that, a user from Account-X should not be able to access any info which belongs to Account-Y. Any help will be appreciated?

Using Asp.Net MVC 4 with C#.

Although there is a good argument you can find here [To Multi-Tenant, or Not To Multi-tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596755/to-multi-tenant-or-not-to-multi-tenant?rq=1)

**Further Clarity:**
How to approach the data access, so the data from diff. accounts are protected from each other. There is one database instance to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Claim based authorization`

Comment: can you be more specific with sample code ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing in right direction. I can't say i have got my answer here, but it seems to go in the reqd. way.